# Vue application loaded on a sub page will have its URL updated to site start page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to load a Vue application on one of my sub pages. The site is an Episerver CMS site running ASP .NET on IIS.

When trying to load my Vue application on one of my sub pages, the url is changed to my start page url. The application works fine but since the url is changed, the application breaks on page refresh.

I'm using Vue router with hash mode (Hash mode is REQUIRED. **When using history mode everything works fine**).

Let say my application is loaded on the following url:

https://www.example.com/subpage/appstart/

My route configuration:

```
{
  mode: 'hash',
  base: '/',
  [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/page1',
      name: 'page1',
      component: Page
    },
  ],
}
```

I've tried to use '/subpage/appstart/' as base but that does not seem to have any effect when using hash mode?

When navigating to my application:

https://www.example.com/subpage/appstart/

The url is changed to:

https://www.example.com/#/

The application works and so does the routing. Navigating to one of the pages will end up using the following url:

https://www.example.com/#/page1

How can I make the application work from the correct root url, so that my application Home stays on the correct url:

https://www.example.com/subpage/appstart/#/

https://www.example.com/subpage/appstart/#/page1

Comment: Could you double-check that changing the `base` value doesn't have an effect? From the [source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/c3b0a335f7947584a7fc37ad0b87d55fe33dd039/src/history/hash.js#L84-L86) it looks like it should have an effect.

Comment: I double checked and get the same result. I tried to set up a new IIS site which just pointed to a folder simulating my site structure and this works: http://vuesite.local/subpage/appstart/#/. 

Maybe there is some issue with ASP.NET Mvc routing or Episerver routing?

Comment: @DelenaMalan I created a new clean project using Vue CLI and added vue-router in project setup. When I start running my application with 'npm run serve', nothing happens when setting 'base' option to '/test/'. However, when switching to history mode, it starts adding '/test/' to my urls.